# unable to generate a CRUD in symfony 3.0.0

Tags: php, crud, symfony

As in earlier version of symfony we user to generate a CRUD with the following command

```
$ php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

But in symfony 3.0.0 i could not find the app/console, even I tried checking the documentation for the same but was not able to find anything.

Link to document http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

Comment: Use in Symfony2:

`php app/console`

Use in Symfony3:

`php bin/console`

Answer (score 4):

Use bin/console instead of app/console.

However, Symfony 3.0 was just released yesterday. http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-0-released. Most of the core concepts between S2 and S3 are the same but the implementations have changed significantly.  For example, the form components work differently.  Most of the current documentation is S2 specific and will not work under S3. Furthermore, many 3rd party bundles such as FOSUserBundle will not currently work under S3.

So, if want to use bleeding edge software then roll up your sleeves and start reading the upgrade files as well as the blog.

If you just want to make applications then start over with S2.8.

Something else that will be really fun.  The 'current' documents now point to S3.  So most of the S2 links will now point to incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 3 console is moved inside bin folder. So command should be

```
$ php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud
```